# Galaxy Note 8 unresponsive to touch input

Tags: touchscreen, samsung-galaxy-note-8

I've been pulling my hair out over this one for a while now and have been unable to find anything on Google to help.

I recently bought a Samsung Galaxy Note 8 (wifi UK version) and found a very annoying issue with it.  I've found that whilst using touch input, the screen can become unresponsive to touch for a few seconds.  This seems to happen once every 5-10 minutes and lasts 3-5 seconds or so.  It's especially annoying when playing games that rely on touch input.  It's most noticeable with Plants Vs Zombies and Scribblenauts.

The tablet as a whole isn't hanging or crashing, because the game is still running, the music still playing and the screen still updating.  It just doesn't register any touch input.

The only thing I found that might have been remotely helpful to this issue was a forum post claiming that Dropbox could cause this.  I disabled Dropbox on the device and didn't notice any improvement.

I believe the firmware revision is 4.1.2 Jelly Bean.

Does anyone know what to do about this?

UPDATE: The 4.2.2 firmware became available for this device yesterday.  Installing it seems to have resolved the issue (so far).

Comment: Please do let us know if the 4.2.2 update fixes things.

Comment: I'll be keeping a close eye on it, but so far so good.  No input unresponsiveness incidents in the couple of hours I've had so far to play with it.

Comment: If you feel like it's all gone, I would suggest answering your own question as well. Make sure you put a little more than "Upgraded to 4.2 and it works now," of course. Specify whether it was an OTA update, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the issue was in either Jellybean 4.1 or Samsung's supporting software.  I've upgraded the tablet to the official 4.2 firmware and have had no recurrences of the problem described above.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, for anyone else potentially having similar problems, you can try using the stylus instead as it runs off a completely separate magnetic-induction-based digitizer.